# My machine learning question wasn't re-opened, even after I made the required edit

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63433568/how-to-determine-if-a-machine-learning-model-has-been-overfitted-with-regard-to) wasn't opened even after I made the required edit by making it to be specific to my problem.

Screenshot for users with <10k reputation:

[image: screenshot of the question, closed and deleted]

How much time does it take for the change to be made by the moderators?

Comment: I think instead of asking how long it takes for your Question to be handled in the re-open queue, you could have asked **if** your Question is now OK for Stack Overflow and if not: What you may have missed or what you should change.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you for the suggestion. But I have seen many similar questions on Stack Overflow with many upvotes. That's why, I asked.

Comment: You didn't make the required edit. Unfortunately because it has an upvoted answer, it will remain on SO and not get automatically deleted. I guess the delete voters wanted to fix that situation.

Comment: @Trilarion The question *was* edited to give it more focus, but that made it clear it was off-topic for this site. Please see the comments [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219937/discussion-on-answer-by-ryan-m-my-machine-learning-question-wasnt-re-opened-ev) under Ryan M's answer here for further details.

Answer (score 23):

First of all: your edit does not fix the problem, which is that this isn't a specific programming question.  It's a statistics/data science/machine-learning question: specifically, it's [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81576/291591), which already has a very detailed answer on a more appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Second: Your question was edited 47 minutes ago and entered the reopen queue at that point.  This review is performed mostly by non-moderators with the [cast close and reopen votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), rather than by [site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators). It has [not yet received any votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26945161).  It can take anywhere between an hour or two and a few days, depending on how clearly good/bad the question is and how many subject-matter experts are looking at the queue.  However, in its current state, I believe it is unlikely to be reopened, for the reason in the first paragraph, and because this is clear to people with no domain knowledge, it is likely to receive these votes on the shorter end of that timeframe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219937/discussion-on-answer-by-ryan-m-my-machine-learning-question-wasnt-re-opened-ev).